# Access to main Vue instance in App.vue script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In Vue2, I'm trying to set up an `axios` interceptor in my `App.vue` file to trap any responses that come back `401` from my API so I can redirect the user to the Vue route `/sign-in`. My code works, *but* I rely on storing the Vue instance created in `main.js` in `window.appvue`.

In `main.js`:

```
window.appvue = new Vue({
    router,
    render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

In `App.vue`:

```
<script>
import...
export default { ... }
 
export const $axios = axios.create();
$axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    (error) => {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
            window.appvue.$router.push("/sign-in");
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    }
);
<script>
```

I have tried importing `$axios` from `App.vue` in `main.js` and moving the `$axios.interceptors.response.use(...)` code to that file, but then the interceptor never runs when I have a page where an `$axios.get()` returns 401.

Is there a way to accomplish this without storing the main Vue instance in `window` as a global? Or should I just go with what's working and call it a day?

---

**P.S.**
I was not aware of the existence of `$root`, when I asked this question, and I have not tried a version where the code in `App.vue` uses `$root` instead of relying on the `window.appvue` global, but when it comes to accessing the main/root instance of Vue from `main.js`, `$root` is definitely preferable to a global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to avoid using the global by isolating the `axios` wrapper into its own module/file. Then my `.vue` files that need `axios` can import from that instead of from `axios` directly

In `{root}/src/axios.js`:

```
import axios from "axios";
import router from "@/router";

const $axios = axios.create();
$axios.interceptors.response.use(
    [stuff that uses router]
);
export default $axios;
```

Then in my files that need to call to the API:

```
import $axios from "@/axios.js";
```

and use `$axios` instead of `axios` to make the API call.

Answer (score 0):

inside your `main.js` try something like this

```js
import router from './router'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.prototype.axios.interceptors.reponse.use(
  res => {
    // res stuff here
  },
  err => {
    // error stuff here
    if (err.response.status === 401) {
      router.push("/sign-in");
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: I get this error message in the browser: `Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.prototype.axios is undefined`. I could define it, I suppose, or add it to the Vue instance itself as a property.